# robot framework RIDE .jar-import and libdoc-generation

Tags: python, jar, jython, robotframework

I want to import my own java-keywords in robot. the importet .jar-file is always red, but I think that I need a XML-file(?). 
Is it needed to create with libdoc the XML and only after this, I can import my own lib?

The following code didn't helped...

```
# Create spec for a Java based library
CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/sun-java-6/lib/tools.jar:myjavalib-0.1.jar jython libdoc.py -f XML MyJavaLibrary
```

Any Ideas to import my .jar?

Comment: are you asking about RIDE, or about how to use a jar file when running a test. If you're only concerned about running a test, you don't need the .xml file.

Comment: I want to use a jar file with own keywords for ride. xml was only an idea.

Comment: the reason I ask is that RIDE and robot are two different things. It's not clear if you're trying to solve a RIDE problem or a robot problem.

Comment: ok, it's about RIDE because the interface ist needed.